# What is use of 'initial' value in CSS?

Tags: html, css, browser

I thought that the `initial` value would restore initially rendered styles (as applied by a browser's internal user-agent stylesheet).

Example:

```
div.inline {
  display: inline;
}

div.initial {
  display: initial;
}
```

I expected the `div.inline` rule would display `<div class="inline">` in inline mode, and the `div.initial` rule would display `<div class="initial">` using a `div`'s original display value of `block`.

But when I explore this, `<div class="initial">` displays inline. Am I wrong? Can anyone elaborate more on this?

Comment: Here's a good explanation for initial value: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35689456/3597276

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The [`initial` value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#common-keywords) (not attribute) denotes the initial value of the property, as defined in CSS specifications: “The ‘initial’ keyword represents the specified value that is designated as the property's initial value.” Thus, its meaning depends on the property, but not on anything else, e.g. not on the browser or on the element that the property is being applied to. So it does *not* mean browser default.

For example, for the `display` property, `initial` *always* means `inline`, because that’s the designated initial value of the property. In the example case, the *browser default* is `block`, since the element is `div`.

Thus, the `initial` value is of limited usefulness. Its main effect seems to be to confuse people, due to misunderstandings. A possible use case is for the `color` property, since its initial value is browser-dependent (mostly black, as we know, but not necessarily). For it, `initial` means browser default, since that’s how the property has been defined, A similar use case is for `font-family`: by declaring `font-family: initial`, you get browser’s default font (which may depend on browser settings).

The usefulness is further limited by lack of support on IE (even IE 10).

Comment: There is one very common annoying use case where `initial` is *extremely* helpful: when you hide and unhide an element programmatically, i.e. give it `display:none` then display it again. This is because there are so many values for `display`, and no defaults without `initial`. jQuery has been doing this for years, and preprocessors like LESS, Stylus & SCSS make it easier, but it's helpful that it's right in CSS. IE not having it does limit it, though, especially since the others do allow it there.

Comment: Sorry, got carried away there. Maybe I'll put it in an answer when I feel more productive.

Comment: @trysis: `display: initial` is a synonym for `disply: inline` when it even works at all, so that doesn't buy you much.

Comment: The initial value is what is used when the browser renders unrecognized or unsupported HTML elements. http://stackoverflow.com/q/35689456/3597276

Comment: @trysis, can you pls simplify it. I don't fully comprehend with what you meant by `There is one very common annoying use case where initial is extremely helpful:...`. preferably with an example..thks

Comment: It also has the use of frustrating devs like me, that just want `2*initial` to be a thing for "twice the default value".

Comment: @trysis, I'm also confused by your comment about the "one very common annoying use case where `initial` is extremely helpful." It sounds like you're saying that "display: initial" can be used when you've hidden an element with "display: none" and then want to show it again, restoring whatever "display" property it had before you hid it. That doesn't work. It just gives the element a "display" property of "inline," regardless of whether it's a block-level element such as a <div> or an inline element such as a <span>. If you're saying something different, could you please clarify?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that comment a long time ago, when Inwas a brand new developer. I meant `display: revert`. Unfortunately, `revert` doesn't have very good support, even now.

Comment: `revert` has now 93% support. @trysis

Comment: @AntoineWeber Yes, and it's great! Of course, even now, some clients just won't give up on IE, even years after M$ gave up on it.

Comment: The `revert` value is something different. It might be what people expected `initial`` to be, but the question is still about `initial` (which is a well-defined and mostly useless value).

Answer (score 7):

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial)

> The initial CSS keyword applies the initial value of a property to an element. It is allowed on every CSS property and causes the element for which it is specified to use the initial value of the property.

```
/* give headers a green border */
 h2 { border: medium solid green }

 /* but make those in the sidebar use the value of the "color" property */
 #sidebar h2 { border-color: initial; }
<p style="color:red"> 
    this text is red 
       <em style="color:initial"> 
          this text is in the initial color (e.g. black)
       </em>
    this is red again
 </p>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Then what is the diff btwn `inherit` and `initial`?

Comment: `inherit` gets its value from the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

Summary: **The most common use of the `initial` value is to override inherited styles.**

When you use an [inherited property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance#inherited_properties) on an element, some of its descendants might be affected undesirably. To wipe out the unwanted style from those elements, use the `initial` value.

```css
p {
  visibility: hidden;
}

em {
  visibility: initial;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>This text is hidden.</span>
  <em>I don't want this text to be hidden.</em>
  <span>This text is hidden.</span>
</p>
```

Then what's the difference between [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) and the [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) property, which is discussed in the OP? The `visibility` property can be inherited, but `display` cannot:

[image]

[image]

On [non-inherited properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance#non-inherited_properties), the property's `initial` value may be unexpectedly different form the browser's default value. That means you need to know its `initial` value before you use it. Nevertheless, the computed (final) value may be different form the `initial` value:

```css
p {
  display: flex;
}

a {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</p>
```

[image]

That's why I personally prefer not to use the `initial` value on non-inherited properties.