# Remove CSS Effect Without Effecting It

Tags: html, css

How can I plain old just the value of margin-left on !important? Here is a example:

```
.property{
  margin-left: -10%;
}
.property.more{
  margin-left: no value here;
}
```

I would like the margin-left to be like it was never set. I have tried calc (even none) and everything, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: there's `initial`, which may be what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534561/what-is-use-of-initial-value-in-css

Comment: Hmm, no I am trying everything. Whenever I use any of them it just sets it at the same as 0px. The original value is -20%, and I need to override it to none.

Comment: did you try 'margin-left: auto !important;'?

Comment: Yes :( It will not work, I think I will just set it manually

Comment: @michaeljones how about `0%` ?

Comment: No, I think I can get it to work with inherit though, thank you guys!

Comment: @michaeljones It sounds like the `-10%` should be the property set by an extra class, then you just remove that class - would be much cleaner

Comment: Please include an online minimal example to the question next time If you do not want to waste people's time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `inherit`/`initial` as margin left

```
.property.more{
  margin-left: inherit !important;
}
```

**initial**     Will sets this property to its default value

**inherit**     Will set make it inherit this property from its parent element

[Read more](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin.asp) to understand how values work

**Update:** Making `!important` depends on what other js/css manipulation you make that effects `precedence`

so

```
.property.more{
      margin-left: inherit;
    }
```

In your case as @smokeyPHP said '.property.more is more specific than .property'. this will work fine.

Comment: Is the important necessary? `.property.more` is more specific than `.property` and should therefore override it anyway

Comment: @SmokeyPHP thanks for mentioning i edited the answer as per your pointed suggestion

Comment: @michaeljones And definitely `inherit` doesn't make `margin-left to be like it was never set`. It forces the element to *inherit* the value from its parent.

Comment: @HashemQolami your are right,complete html context will be brought into consideration

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about IE support, you can use [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) or [`unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset)