# I want to override the style set by my stylesheet to the default style for an ordered list

Tags: html, css

I have this html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>"This is my first page"</title>
<link href="assignment3-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <ol style="I want the default style here">

        </ol>
    </p>
```

I want to override the style set by my stylesheet with the default style for ordered lists. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Use a validator. http://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: Sorry i am new to html. thanks for the link.

Comment: @Quentin: Your answer was (and still is) correct - you shouldn't have deleted it IMO. Though this question may conceivably be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228980/reset-css-display-property-to-default-value anyway, just with a different set of properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update: As of now, there is no reasonable way in CSS to reset to default styles. You will have to reset each and every property manually.

#### Just for reference purposes, here's my old - and *wrong* - answer:

Unless you want to reset all your `<ol>`, put a specific class on it, let's call it `default-style`.

For this class, then define in CSS

CSS:

`.default-style {` <del>`all: initial;`</del> `}` **<-- [This will NOT work!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534561/what-is-use-of-initial-value-in-css)**

HTML:

```
<ol class="default-style">
     <!-- your <li>s here -->
</ol>
```

If you want only certain CSS properties to default, set `initial` as their value, for example `margin: initial;`.

> http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-inheritance-tips-tricks/

Comment: Initial is not the same as browser default. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228980/reset-css-display-property-to-default-value/8229026#8229026 In this specific case, although the default display of an ol is block, all: initial will reset it to inline, because the initial value of display is inline.

Comment: So the browser won't take the default styles for the element type that `all: initial;` is applied to into account? If that's true, what's the purpose of `initial` as a property value?

Comment: Honestly, [nobody knows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534561/what-is-use-of-initial-value-in-css). Presumably it was put in for the sake of completeness, since CSS itself defines the concept of an initial value.

Comment: While this does not provide a solution to my issue it does answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply look in the css file where it effects the specific elements you want in default style and delete the css code, or make it more specific. Suppose you wanted `ol` to be in default styling for most instances, but wanted to keep the original code found in this stylesheet. You could simply do something like the following:

```
ol .not-default {
/*code that was already here*/
}
```

That way whenever you do not want default styling, you would simply write the following:

```
<ol class="not-default">Yay a stylish ordered list!</ol>
```

Hope that helps!